# Doctrine. QueryBuilder. How to attach all categories with all options to query results

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine

I dont know how to attach array of optins and categories for a single dish. I'm getting only one category and only one option as a query result. Help please :)
I have a dish. That can be connected to some categories with options.

Dish - Pizza
Options Category - Addons
Options - double cheese, salami, pepper, onion

Dish - Salad
Options Category - Sauce
Options - olive, mustard, sour cream

I have also a dish that can be connected with more than one options category.

Dish - Special Dish
Options Category - Addons
Options - double cheese, salami, pepper, onion
Options Category - Sauce
Options - olive, mustard, sour cream

Example database data:

Dish 
----  
(id,name)
1,Pizza
2,Salad
3,Special Dish

```
  | 1..n
  V
```

Dish_Options_Category_Assoc
---------------------------
(id, dish_id, category_id)
1, 1, 6
2, 2, 7
3, 3, 6
4, 3, 7

```
  | n..1
  V
```

Dish_Options_Category
---------------------
(id, name)
6, Addons
7, Sauce

```
  | 1..n
  V
```

Dish_Options
------------
(id, category_id, name)
11, 6, double cheese
12, 6, salami
13, 6, pepper
14, 6, onion
15, 7, olive
16, 7, mustard
17, 7, sour cream

In dish_options_category_assoc repository I'm looking for all dishes, with all categories and (i want to connect also all Options)

```
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
       ->where('d.dish = :did')
       ->join('d.categoryAssoc','ct')
       ->setParameters(array("did"=> $id)) 
       ->select('(d.dish) as dish_id','ct.id as cat_id','ct.name as cat_name')
       ->leftJoin('ct.options', 'o')
       ->addSelect('o.name as options')
       ->getQuery() 
       ->getResult();

    return $q;
```

But I'm getting only one category and only one option.

Data I got for one "Special dish" that have 2 different option categories attached: (corrected query above)

Array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["dish_id"]=> "3"
    ["cat_id"]=> "6"
    ["cat_name"]=> "Addons"
    ["options"]=> "double cheese"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["dish_id"]=> "3"
    ["cat_id"]=> "6"
    ["cat_name"]=> "Addons"
    ["options"]=> "salami"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["dish_id"]=> "3"
    ["cat_id"]=> "6"
    ["cat_name"]=> "Addons"
    ["options"]=> "pepper"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["dish_id"]=> "3"
    ["cat_id"]=> "6"
    ["cat_name"]=> "Addons"
    ["options"]=> "onion"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["dish_id"]=> "3"
    ["cat_id"]=> "7"
    ["cat_name"]=> "Sauce"
    ["options"]=> "olive"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["dish_id"]=> "3"
    ["cat_id"]=> "7"
    ["cat_name"]=> "Sauce"
    ["options"]=> "mustard"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["dish_id"]=> "3"
    ["cat_id"]=> "7"
    ["cat_name"]=> "Sauce"
    ["options"]=> "sour cream"
  }
}

Can anyone tell me how to attach categories, and options as array for a dish ?

Comment: can you dump your query to see what it does please?

Comment: Do you want to use `getScalarResult`? Try to remove the `groupBy`, remove the `select` and `addSelect`, replace `getScalarResult` with `getResult`.

Comment: @hoover thanks, I present the results with corrected query as proposed.

Comment: @Kim without addSelect there are no options visible at all so I have put it.

Comment: Without ->select and ->addSelect dump() prints nothing and var_dump() kills my browser and I can't parse it. I want to take this data in array because I need to read all these values in Twig.

Comment: With my solution you will not receive an array with text-data, but an array containing hydrated objects. So an array with elements of type `Dish_Options_Category_Assoc`. You can just foreach that and access each object.

Comment: Yes @Kim It is as You are saying. I just changed select and addSelect to ->select('d','ct','o') and I got data like You mentioned. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: nice @theurgicus , maybe post your final change as answer here.

Comment: Ok. Ready. Thank You ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - Dish info with option categories and with options:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->where('d.dish = :did')
    ->join('d.categoryAssoc','ct')
    ->setParameters(array("did"=> $id)) 
    ->leftJoin('ct.options', 'o')
    ->select('d','ct','o')
    ->getQuery() 
    ->getResult();

return $q;
```